# Switch Option Key behavior globally to match terminal "Meta" key functionality

Tags: terminal, keyboard, emacs

I use/love emacs and I also love using emacs like navigation text in MacOS, e.g. "Meta-b" moves the cursor to the beginning of the last word. Most emacs navigation works by default including "Option-delete" which deletes the last whole word. However the option key has most of the keyboard mapped to silly symbols like "Option-b" which makes "∫" and "Option-f" which makes "ƒ". I never use these symbols (who does?).

In MacOS Terminal, there is a check box in Preferences > Basic > Keyboard which turns the option key into a strict "Meta" key and removes the dumb "insert symbol" functionality.

How does one do this globally?

Comment: Are you talking about Emacs for MacOS?  Or using emacs type navigation in standard MacOS apps?

Comment: See if this helps:  https://jblevins.org/log/kbd

Comment: From which there is a link to https://github.com/nileshk/mac-configuration/blob/99eef47cd434fd3d6f4f1f9e2f50321f32179b88/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict but I have no idea if that still works